# iOS CALayer pixel intersection?

Tags: ios, core-animation, calayer, core-image

I'm looking for a way to determine whether two CALayers turn on any pixels (to any color at all) in common.

I can set one layer as the mask of the other, and get a result that will only have such pixels. But now, is there a way of determining whether any of those pixels has alpha > 0?  This operation would have to be extremely fast. It would be equivalent to determine the pixel maximum or minimum.

I'd rather not have to create an image and run down all the pixels by hand on the cpu. It would seem that CIFilter ought to be able to do this, so it could run on the gpu, but all of the filters I can find produce more images (I want a single boolean). Can GPUImage do this? Metal?

Just checking for anyone's experience before I go down these rabbit holes...

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong: it *is* fast enough for my purposes (meaning keep user responsiveness) to do the intersection on the cpu, without having to resort to gpu programming. I initially thought it wasn't, because I was using a library that called an objective-c method in the inner loop to determine whether each pixel was on or off. That was slow. When I redid it in c++ using an inline function, it was plenty fast.